# Do we have evidence of clipped words in Latin?

Tags: example-request, vulgar-latin

In English, it's common for words to be clipped down to their first couple syllables: "brother" becomes "bro", "university" becomes "uni", "doctor" becomes "doc", "veteran" becomes "vet", and so on. [This question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/10895/406) mentions the similar Italian *frater* > *fra*.

Is there evidence of this happening in Latin? It seems like a very common linguistic process, and while Vergil and Cicero may not have put it down in writing, it might plausibly show up in graffiti or leave traces in Romance.

Comment: Domnus > Dom/Don in Romance and sor(or) come to mind. I hope I can spare some time to do the research

Comment: @Rafael That sounds like exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: Yes, but your question was about Latin, not Romance.

Comment: @Draconis: net: "Latin Abbreviations--Part 3: Word Contractions".

Comment: @fdb True, but if something happens consistently across the Romance languages, that's a good clue that it could already have been happening in Vulgar Latin.